# Can I export my funds from blockchain.info with the backup phrase?

Tags: blockchain.info

For some reason lately Blockchain.info's 2FA emails haven't come through. I tried resetting 2FA emails with my back-up keys and did it successfully but now the 2FA emails aren't coming to the new email. So something is totally off on their side. Is there a way I can export my funds (BTC/ETH) out from blockchain.info without knowing the private keys for my addresses but only the back-up phrase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by "backup phrase" the Mnemonic phrase which is 12 word for blockchain so the answer is yes, you can export your funds.

Assume you want to import your mnemonic phrase to electrm

you have to choose that your mnemonic phrase is bip39 seed, not electrum seed.

Then they will ask about derivation path you leave it `44` (default) for blockchain.

Comment: Thank you! Downloaded Electrum and gave this a try just now. Couple of issues though:
1) It's showing that I have approx 4x less available BTC in my wallet. Maybe it hasn't fully updated yet?
2) Also had ETH on my blockchain account, is there a way to recover these as well? Maybe with some multi-currency wallet like Jaxx or Exodus? 

Thank you again!

Comment: Your further questions shouldn't be asked in comments section. Electrum doesn't support Ethereum, even it does support Etherum you are connecting to bitcoin network.

Comment: Ok. Interestingly enough I got access back to blockchain via recovering my password. They gave me a new wallet identifier though.

Comment: Also, any idea why Electrum would show smaller balance compared to blockchain for BTC?

Comment: Please ask another question with more details. There are many reasons to have that and I can't mention it all in here, you should ask another question with enough details.